# When you have a number which has over 1 digit in a created board, what should you do prevent it from affecting the shape of the board

Tags: c++

I am new to C++. And I am trying to implement a 2048 game based on C++ for practice. And I am trying to create a board first.

The problem I have is that when the number is become a two digit numbers it will affect the shape of the wall like this:

[image]

Here is the test code:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string gameboard[24][25];
    int p = 24 / 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < 24;i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 25; j++)
        {
            if (i == 0 || j == 0 || i == 23|| j == 24 || (i % p) == 0 || (j % p) == 0)
            {
                gameboard[i][j] = '*';
            }
            else
            {
                gameboard[i][j] = " ";
            }
        }
    }

    gameboard[3][15] = "128";
    for (int i = 0; i < 24; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 25; ++j)
        {
            cout << gameboard[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

So I put a string number "128", it will break the wall. What should I do to prevent this?

Comment: How should “128” be drawn in 2 character spots?

Comment: print each entry with a fixed width of 4 and adjust the walls accordingly

Comment: [`std::setw`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you actually want a `char gameboard[24][25];` rather than a 2d array of strings. When each cell of the board is exactly 1 character wide then you just need to print it character by character to get expected output.

If you do that you need to place individual digits rather than the complete number as string:

```
gameboard[3][13] = '1';
gameboard[3][14] = '2';
gameboard[3][15] = '8';
```

I recommend to wrap this inside a function:

```
void place_number(int number, int row, int col,char gameboard[24][25]) {
      int x = row * a + b;
      int y = col * c + d;
      std::string s = std::to_string(number);
      for (int i=0; i<s.size(); ++i) {
         gameboard[x][y+i] = s[i];
      }
}
```

With coefficients `a`,`b`,`c` and `d` choosen such that the numbers end up in the right positions.

Doing such formatted printing can become cumbersome rather fast. If you need more sophisticated control I suggest to use a library for that, for example ncurses.

Answer (score 0):

from the 25 places reserved for the width, you should consider to substract the number of placed occupied for the number you print in the cell..

you can turn the number to std::string and take its length
or mathematically get the number of digits using some existing functions like **log**